# Where to find historical fundamental data of S&P constituents in Thomson Reuters database?

Tags: time-series, historical-data, database, fundamentals, reuters

I need data such as Net Income, ROA, ROE, etc. for companies in S&P 500 Index. I would like to see the values also for other years, e.g., since 2010. However, when I log-in to Thomson Reuters Eikon and click on S&P 500 Index -> constituents analysis -> fundamentals, I see only a snapshot of current values.

Can I obtain also historical data? If yes, how?

Thank you very much.

Aneta

Comment: Since you seem to have a Reuters license: did you contact their support and ask them this?

Answer (score 0):

The historical fundamentals can also be found in Thomson Reuters EIKON. In the Menu Bar, click on "Fundamentals". The Snapshot shows recent values. Try to find the "Standardized Financials". There is a good overview of all historical annual statements, including the named Ratios like ROA, ROE. If not, there could be a subscription issue. Call TR Customer Service else.